# How to update a form progress bar after sending form's value to another php script using jquery/ajax in wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am developing a wordpress plugin which has a form for voting purpose and has a progress bar for showing the votes result. After submitting the form it redirects to another page for processing. But I want to submit the form without page refresh. I could do it with jquery/ajax. But the problem is, after submitting the form without page reload ajax will submit the form data to a php page and it will keep those data to database ,but the voting poll result will not be updated (progress bar will not display latest information ,after submitting ajax data,though data is updated in database)  if user does not reload the page.

Please give me an idea how could I do that.

Comment: Can't you update the poll / progress bar via AJAX ?

Comment: You are saving the data in db, and your plug in calculates the % from the data in databases. so AFTER you have saved the data, You can fetch the latest polls and update the progress bar in (say) `onSuccess` of AJAX call.

Comment: I can send poll data , but I cant update progress bar.Suppose, in my voting poll I have received two votes. And the plugin finds out the total vote in percentage . My progress bar works like below

<img src='some_img_link' height='3' width='percentage which plugin has finds out' />

If any user submits another vote , then everything works but progress bar does not update. To update the progress bar users have to reload the page. What I do not want.

Comment: I guess you're calculating the % when the page is requested ?

Comment: To say in a single word I need to send the form via ajax/jquery.Then my progress bar will show latest data including latest vote which user submitted just now

Comment: If you have the code for calculating % (which I assume you do have) then you can do the following

1. store data in db via ajax call
2. retrieve the updated data
3. fire up your 'calculation code'
4. now you have the %.
5. update the `width` attribute of image `onSuccess` of AJAX call.

Answer (score 0):

After the poll data has processed, send a script back to the main page:

```
<script>

document.getElementById('myProgressBarId').setAttribute("width","50%");

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the code for calculating % (which I assume you do have) then you can do the following in your AJAX call.

1. Store data in db.
2. Retrieve the updated data
3. Fire up your 'calculation code'
4. Now you have the %.
5. Update the width attribute of image `onSuccess` of AJAX call.

The jQuery way:

```
$.ajax({ 

//other code

success : function(data) { 
    $('#progress-bar-image').attr('width', data);
}

//data is the calculated percentage.
});
```

See [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) doc